# Why can't I use a number wildcard to in Cells.Find in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to search my Excel worksheet for any cell that has a value that begins with a number followed by a period, but this isn't working. Does anyone know why not?

```
Cells.Find(What:="[0-9].", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm trying to search my Excel worksheet for any cell that has a value that begins with a number followed by a period but this isn't working.

> Does anyone know why not?

A period `.` has a special meaning in a regular expression, it means "Matches any single character".

If you want to match a literal period `.` you need to escape the special meaning. `\` is used as the escape character (for example `"\."`, `"\\"`).

So your expression should be `"[0-9]\."` in order to match a literal period `.`.

To match more than one digit followed by a period use `"[0-9]+\."` (`+` is used to match the preceding expression one or more times).

See [VBA RegEx: How to Evaluate and Use “Regular Expressions”](https://www.udemy.com/blog/vba-regex/) for more information.

Note: **As far as I am aware `cells.find()` does not support regular expressions.**

You need to use the `RegExp` class.

> Regular Expressions (RegExp) is a class that offers incredibly powerful text parsing capabilities, in particular allowing users to find (and even replace) substrings within larger text entries that fit a particular pattern.  This article provides basic information on the VBScript implementation of RegExp, and how you can use it to gain robust text parsing capabilities in Visual Basic 6 (VB6) and Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) projects.  With a little knowledge of the rules and some imagination, you can build incredibly flexible and/or complex patterns.

...

> By adding these functions to your VB6/VBA projects, you can quickly and easily incorporate RegExp functionality into your applications.  **If you are a Microsoft Office user, you can even use these functions in worksheet formulas for Microsoft Excel** or in queries in Microsoft Access.

Source [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Basic for Applications and Visual Basic 6](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/A_1336-Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html) for more information.